# Getting unique result from database

Tags: mysql, unique

I have table with the following columns

id, name, score

that has rows

```
1, JohnDoe, 1200
2, JohnDoe, 1600
3, Mickey, 1100
```

Basically, after every time the game is played, the score is inserted into the database.

Eventually, when showing the top-scores, I want just to fetch the best result of a certain player. In this case, I want to fetch JohnDoe's score of 1600 and after that Mickey's score of 1100, but not again JohnDoe's score of 1200 as that is lower than his top one.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to group by the name, and then get the maximum score for each name.**

```
SELECT name, MAX(score) AS "High Score"
FROM ScoreTable
GROUP BY name;
```

Given your table `ScoreTable`:

```
1, JohnDoe, 1200
2, JohnDoe, 1600
3, Mickey, 1100
```

The query above would return:

```
      Name | High Score
   JohnDoe | 1600
    Mickey | 1100
```

You would probably also want to sort by high score to show JohnDoe before Mickey (show the highest score first):

```
SELECT name, MAX(score) AS "High Score"
FROM ScoreTable
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY "High Score" DESC;
```

You can check it out in [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2af43/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,max(score)
from table_name
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, max(score) as score
from tablename
group by name
```

**[Read Group By function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)**

**[SQl Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/422e2/2)**

Answer (score 0):

#### Use aggregation in database

```
SELECT name, MAX(score)
FROM <your_table_name>
GROUP BY name;
```